# Get content from one branch to another repositories branch

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I want to get my files from one branch to another repositories branch. Instead of just copying the files on my file-system, is there some fancy command I could use for this task?

Also, is there a quick way to do this with SourceTree? My colleagues need to do this (sooner or later) as well and they prefer not to use the command-line.

Comment: If you really need to move content across _repositories_, I'm not aware of a nice way of doing this.  Can you elaborate on what you need to move?

Comment: Its just some of our project-related files. The target-repository is owned by our client and should only receive working versions of our software. The source-repository is the one we‘re working on.

Comment: Why would you want to copy the history of one repo to another?

Comment: @OfficerBacon Has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 0):

To get the files from a branch to antoher repository repo, you can use use way:

Asumme copy the files from `dev` branch of repoA to `master` branch of repoB, you can run below commands in local `repoB`:

```
#In local repoB
git remote add repoA <URL for repoA> -f
 git checkout repoA/dev -- .
git commit -m 'get files from repoA dev branch'
git push origin master
```

**Note:** when checkout the files from repoA `dev` branch to repoB `master` branch, it will overwrite all the files from the current working directory. So you should commit the changes on `master` branch before checkout the files from repoA `dev` branch.